# how to use map/set for getting the value by the key name

Tags: apex, map, collection

I am not familiar with the data collections and want the solution. requirement is like:

I want to have object name in the **where** statement for query like:

```
select id , Name from Documents__c where ObjectId = '000002233377'
```

I am getting the object name from

```
ObjectName = objectInstance.getDescribe().getName();
```

now if the ObjectName is '**Account**' the ObjectId in query should be '**Account__c**',
    if the ObjectName is '**Contact**' the ObjectId in query should be '**Contact__c**'

So how can I Get the ObjectId directly the key name if I use map like:

```
    Map<String, String> MyStrings = new Map<String, String>{
                       'Account' => 'Account_id__c', 
                       'Contact' => 'Contact__c',
                       'Insurance Quote' => 'Insurance_Quote__c',
                       'Payment Transaction' => 'Transaction__c'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a [dynamic SOQL query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) where the field queried will vary based on using the type of the SObject to lookup the field name:

```
     ...
     Account a = ...;
     myMethod(a);
     ...

private void myMethod(SObject sob) {
    String objectName = String.valueOf(sob.getSObjectType());
    String field = myStrings.get(objectName);
    String value = sob.Id;                   // '000002233377';
    for (Documents__c d : Database.query(''
            + ' select Id, Name'
            + ' from Documents__c'
            + ' where ' + field + ' = :value'
            ) {
        // Use the Id and Name in here
    }
}
```